# Strange Error Value too great for base when reading after IFS command

Tags: bash, shell

I have the below sample function which does file reading etc.

```
function try_abc() {
 abc_fn="file input.txt";
 abc_0fn="file0.m"
 abc_1fn="file1.m"

 while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8; do
  printf "%04X\n" "$((0x$col1))" >> $abc_0fn
  printf "%04X\n" "$((0x$col2))" >> $abc_1fn
 done < $abc_fn
}
```

If I call this function before IFS read, it works fine like given below.

```
try_abc
default_line=$(head -n 1 $tf)
IFS=$'\n' brr=( $(xargs -n1 <<<"$default_line") )
```

If I call the same function after the IFS read, it fails with the below error.

```
default_line=$(head -n 1 $tf)
IFS=$'\n' brr=( $(xargs -n1 <<<"$default_line") ) 
try_abc
```

Error printed is..

```
00000ABC: value too great for base (error token is "00000ABC")
```

Comment: `Z` is not valid in base 16. Only 0 through 9 and A through F are legal.

Comment: Because your code can't be run with the same output reported without input files only you have, btw, none of the above qualifies as a [mre]

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Just gave an example.. its actually the hex values.. like ABC.. True know have not provided the entire codes as its part of bigger code. Will try to reproduce with example and provide the same. But just captured the essence of the issue above.

Comment: Does the filename really have spaces in it like `file input.txt`? Make sure you put quotes around the variable `$abc_fn`.

Comment: Think it works fine after I unset the IFS. Its because of the delimiter.

Comment: Assuming you're targeting bash 4.0 or later, note that it would be better practice to write `readarray -t brr < <(xargs -n1 <<<"$(head -n1 <"$tf")")` -- that command doesn't need IFS at all and doesn't care what its value is.

Answer (score 1):

After you assign `IFS`, the new IFS is used as the delimiter when assigning the variables in

```
read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

So spaces are no longer treated as column delimiters when reading the file, and the entire line is put into `$col1`.

You should save the old value of `IFS` so you can restore it.

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n' 
brr=( $(xargs -n1 <<<"$default_line") ) 
IFS=$saveIFS
```

You may have been thinking that the `IFS` assignment is just temporary for the line that assigns `brr`. You can put variable assignments before a normal command, and they'll be temporary while the command executes. But that doesn't apply if the remainder of the line is just more variable assignments; this is just multiple assignments and they apply to the current shell permanently.